# Nextjs routing - Catch everything except public folder

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

pages/[...slug].js catches all of my sub folders but I need to exclude /public folder. How can I exclude the /public folder?

I have implemented this code and it works. But I wanted to exclude the /public folder somewhere above the page like next.config.js. Is this possible?

```js
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.asPath.indexOf("/public/") === 0) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(404);
    ctx.res.end();
  } else {
    // renders my page
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean the normal public folder where you save your images in? That folder is excluded by *nextjs* by default. It only looks at stuff inside the pages folder.

Comment: Yes. But if the image is not exist in the public folder, next.js executes this page.
For instance:
/public/vector.svg
This image is not exist and next.js thinks it is a normal page. If I try to reach this address "/public/vector.svg" on the browser I see my pages/[...slug].js page.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But you don't need the public prefix for that because public is never prepended somewhere by *nextjs*. So if the user enters yourdomain.com/vector.svg and the image exists, he would see it.